# How to build React Native Bridge for UWP Library

Tags: c#, react-native, uwp, react-native-bridge

I have a UWP c# library , which I am trying to use from react native windows app.

There are plenty of examples for creating a bridge to communicate between react native and ios or android native library.

But I am not able to find any document or samples to create bridge to communicate between native c# uwp library and react native .

**I WOULD LIKE TO CREATE A BRIDGE - WHICH CAN COMMUNICATE BETWEEN UWP C# LIBRARY AND REACT NATIVE.**

Can anyone help me with any document or samples , would be appreciable.

Thanks.
Noorul.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for React Native for Windows (building RN desktop apps from Windows) you can check this official documentation from Microsoft https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/native-code-language-choice
This part is for UI components https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/view-managers examples based on C#